# background images and scaling

Tags: modeling

Im following a tutorial online but im at a stand still in the video tutorial when he uploads a background image the measurement is 5.000 by default when I upload the same image my measurement is 32.8 were both using the imperial units for measure so I don't know what the problem is can someone help me get my default measurements to 5.000[image]

Comment: Please provide the link to the tutorial (with exact time mention) and elaborate a bit on what is your desired result. As for now it seems that you can fix that just by changing size of the background image entering value (in the slider with value 32.8 in the screenshot).

Comment: to elaborate further he changes his image from 5.000 to 2.6 the problem is if i simply type in 2.6 my image will shrink drastically and will read as 2.6'(feet) while his does not  if you would like to see the tutorial its through lynda.com there is a free 10 day trial if you would like to take a look              https://www.lynda.com/Blender-tutorials/Reviewing-reference-images/360620/384020-4.html?srchtrk=index%3a1%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3ablender%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2 the video is called reviewing reference images the time is 04:45

Answer (score 1):

you can edit that number just to whatever you like..

Comment: Short answers are best as comments.